# Unrecognized Error in MapView (iOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, core-animation, android-mapview

I'm getting an error in MapView that I don't recognize and can't find documentation on. It looks like this:

```
CoreAnimation: ignoring exception: 
Invalid Region <center:-180.00000000, -180.00000000 
                  span:+2.81462803, +28.12500000>
```

Obviously the numbers are exclusive to my code right now but I can't figure out what's going on. The MapView runs just fine and all of my annotations show up (and it zooms on the user's location like I have it set). What specifically does this point to?

Thanks.

---

Here's the method I use to zoom to the user's location. It's a little unorthodox but it's what I've been helped with since I had problems with zooms for a variety of reasons (I can explain if need be, but it's probably not relevant):

```
- (void)zoomToUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userlocation
{
    if (!userlocation)
        return;

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = userlocation.coordinate;
    region.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(2.0, 2.0);
    region = [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];
    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self zoomToUserLocation:self.mapView.userLocation];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)location
{
    [self zoomToUserLocation:location];
}
```

Comment: The center coordinates -180,-180 are invalid.  Somewhere, the code is setting the region.center incorrectly (though it usually crashes in that case).

Comment: region.center = userlocation.coordinate in the method I'm using to zoom to my user's location. 'userlocation' is set as an MKUserLocation in the method so it doesn't seem to make sense...

Comment: Can you please add the method code to the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't tell where the invalid coordinates are coming from but I suggest adding the following checks to the `zoomToUserLocation` method.

Just checking if `userlocation` is `nil` is not enough.  You have to also check if the `location` property inside `userlocation` is nil or not.  *Then*, you can use the `coordinate` property (especially when you're using the coordinates outside the `didUpdateUserLocation` delegate method).

Also, just checking if `coordinate` is `0,0` (technically a valid coordinate) is not recommended as the struct will be "zero" if it's never been set or it could even be filled with random data.  The Core Location framework's `CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid` function is used as the last line of defense to prevent an invalid region.

You could also check the `timestamp` and `horizontalAccuracy` if you want.

```
- (void)zoomToUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userlocation
{
    if (!userlocation)
        return;

    if (!userlocation.location)
    {
        NSLog(@"actual location has not been obtained yet");
        return;
    }

    //optional: check age and/or horizontalAccuracy
    //(technically should check if location.timestamp is nil first)
    NSTimeInterval locationAgeInSeconds = 
        [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:userlocation.location.timestamp];
    if (locationAgeInSeconds > 300)  //adjust max age as needed
    {
        NSLog(@"location data is too old");
        return;
    }

    if (!CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(userlocation.coordinate))
    {
        NSLog(@"userlocation coordinate is invalid");
        return;
    }

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = userlocation.coordinate;
    region.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(2.0, 2.0);

    //region = [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];
    //don't need to call regionThatFits explicitly, setRegion will do it

    [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

Additionally (possibly unrelated and you may have already done this but), based on a couple of your previous questions related to this, you might want to clear and re-set the map view's `delegate` in the map view controller's `viewWillDisappear` and `viewWillAppear` methods to prevent certain errors:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    mapView.delegate = self;
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    mapView.delegate = nil;
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks, those are all great defenses against mapView errors. Doing my best with hands on learning of all of this.

Answer (score 3):

I have found that if you have location services enabled and then display a map view that contains the current user location as an annotation, then disable location services and attempt to use the "location" property of the annotation, the result will be (-180, -180).