# xcode simulator bicycle ride or highway drive coordinates are wrong?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, mapkit

is it just me or is this really a bug that when I set the simulator location to bicycle ride, the latitude is always at 0 , while the longitude is updating?

I keep getting numbers like this when I print out the coordinate:

0, 789442777752750357664707662594831481658901059219640184274.....

Comment: Posting the code _as well as_ your description of the behavior would make a more effective and answerable question.  Where were you logging the coordinates?  How were you logging them?  etc.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

Apparently the  location in the below method which is updating as the bike or car goes around is really wrong. I need to use the aUserLocation instead and create a coordinate myself with its info, to find out the correct current coordinate.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)aUserLocation {
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
```

I don't know why that is but this solved it.

```
 CLLocationCoordinate2D loc;
    loc.latitude = aUserLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    loc.longitude = aUserLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    currentCoordinate = loc;
```

Comment: Were you logging `location` without setting it to `aUserLocation.coordinate`?  Then of course it would log zero or random values.  `location` and `loc` are local variables you've declared that have no automatic connection to any other variable.  Local variables initially contain unpredictable values (but frequently zero).  But you don't need to "create a coordinate" variable yourself because it already exists as `aUserLocation.coordinate` -- you can use and log that directly.

Comment: However, there are cases where user location itself can be invalid even in the delegate method (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394969/unrecognized-error-in-mapview-ios for suggestions on how to handle).